# Docker swarm redis connectivity issue

Tags: docker, redis, swarm

I have following `docker-compose.yml` redis config.

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  db:
    image: redis:latest
    command: redis-server --bind 0.0.0.0 --appendonly yes --protected-mode no

    ports:
      - target: 6379
        published: 6379
        protocol: tcp
        mode: ingress
```

There are two hosts `leader-0` (manager) and `redis-0` (worker)

```
> root@leader-0:~# docker node ls
ID                            HOSTNAME               STATUS     
46tmallxr4l8xr7i90vlwntjq *   leader-0               Ready               
mofbedj4sqlxgnyatbxhlokc7     redis-0                Ready
```

Redis host `redis-0` exposes 6379 port on the localhost as expected:

```
> root@redis-0:~# redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 ping
PONG
```

but 6379 is not available on the manager (although it should):

```
> root@leader-0:~# redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 ping
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection timed out
```

Interesting part is:

1. `Connection timed out` (not refused).
2. `redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 ping` on other workers hosts works as expected (returns `PONG`).

Docker overlay mash network should expose 6379 port on the local interface on each host, but it looks like something went wrong and I messed up figuring out what exactly.

Other services on the manager host works properly (I can 
 `curl http://localhost:${SERVICE_PORT}/`).

Manager host has the same firewall rules as worker hosts (+ additional ports opened)